# Mozbar not showing correct PR/DA info

Tags: seo, google-search

Just installed Mozbar and worked few days fine. Now it's showing Page rank - 1 / Domain authority - 1 in every search results like this.

[image]

Uninstall extension and reinstall,
Chrome browser updated to latest,
Chrome remove and reinstall

Nothing worked :( Finally contacted moz team and they were sending some video tutorial for general issues, not addressing this error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It worked after clearing cookies!